# Migration from visual studio from 2005 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, migration, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to migrate legacy code, consisting of thousand of lines code from visual studio 2005 to visual studio 2015.We have searched all over the internet but haven't found any useful resource.Can anyone please help us regarding this??

Comment: You open the solution and let it convert. If there's some actual problem, please explain. What language, what problems are you getting etc.

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help you:

- According to [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266747.aspx) "Many widely used assets behave the same in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013 and the two earlier versions". You may need convert to VS2012 and use it in VS2015.
- Did you test this: [github](https://github.com/ssvaidya/VSProjectConverter)?
- In the internet there are some articles migrate for example: VS2005 to VS2008 and VS2008 to VS2012. Try to use 2 step conversions.
- The best way to manually migrate: create empty project in VS2012, move your files from the old projects